# Proving if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \nsubseteq C$ then $B \nsubseteq C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-verification, quantifiers

This is one of the problem I have been solving in Velleman's How to prove book:

> Prove that if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \nsubseteq C$ then $B \nsubseteq C$

This is my solution:

> Suppose $A \subseteq B \cap A \nsubseteq C$. Let x be an arbitrary
>    element in A. From $x \in A$ and $A \subseteq B$, it follows that $x
>  \in B$. From $x \in A$ and $A \nsubseteq C$, it follows that $x \notin
>  C$. Therefore, $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$. Since x is arbitrary, $B\nsubseteq C$.

This is the solution given in the book:

> Suppose that $A \subseteq B$ and $A \nsubseteq C$. Since $A \nsubseteq C$, we
>   can choose some $a \in A$ such that $a \notin C$. Since $a\in A$ and $A \subseteq B$,
>   $a \in B$. Since $a \in B$ and $a \notin C$, $B \nsubseteq C$.

The book uses existential quantification to prove it but I assume x as arbitrary and prove that. Is there some flaw in my way of thinking ?

Comment: You might want to clean up the formatting in your post a bit. For example I don't know what is meant by "$x\notin > C$."

Comment: @user38584 Thanks, cleaned it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flaw in your solution is "from $x\in A$ and $A\not\subseteq C$, it follows that $x\not\in C$." This may not be true for *every* $x\in A$, but the hypothesis says that this is true for *at least one*. This is why the solution that you are given uses existential quantification.

For a concrete example, consider $A=\{0,1\}, B=\{0,1,2\}, C=\{0\}$. It is not true that every $x$ in $A$ does not belong to $C$, but this is true for at least one.

Answer (score 2):

A proof of the problem may be obtained if you assume $A\subseteq B \land  B\subseteq C\land A\not\subseteq C$. Because, $$(A\subseteq B \land  B\subseteq C)\land A\not\subseteq C\implies A\subseteq C \land A\not\subseteq C$$
Which surely is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If possible suppose $B\subseteq C$.AS $A\subseteq B$,that would imply $A\subseteq C$,which is a contradiction.